# Plone viewlet managers appear twice

Tags: plone, plone-4.x, viewlets

I'm working on our **Plone 4.2.6** system, currently trying to manage some viewlets.

While working on it, I saw the following order of (relevant) viewlet managers:

`IAboveContentTitle
IAboveContentTitle
IBelowContentBody
IAboveContentBody
IBelowContentBody
IBelowContentBody`

I can't figure out why some viewlet managers appear twice, I saw no difference in their configuration. Also, only viewlets I put in one of the managers appearing twice will be rendered.

Does anyone have a clue what might have gone wrong here?
Thanks in advance!

Edit1: When removing the `<div>` with belowcontentbody from our `main_template.pt`, the manager will only appear once but will not be rendered anymore.

Comment: Have you been fiddling with themes? Can you export the viewlet settings (manage - portal_setup - export - viewlets) and show us an excerpt?

Comment: Are you using a theme with Diazo?

Comment: @LucaFabbri made me think of a bug in Diazo rules too.  But this is Plone 4.2 - does Diazo even work on that?

Comment: @Danimal yes, *if* you are using it.

Comment: Hey, I'm not using Diazo. About the fiddling with themes - might be the case since I'm yet diving into a pre-existing system. IThis is the `viewlets.xml` I get from portal_setup export:  www.github.com/artemisclyde/plone/blob/viewlets/viewlets.xml

Comment: It appears that however I change my `profiles/default/viewlets.xml`, it won't change the exported viewlets.xml file. It only breaks importing when I add wrong syntax.